# 3D Follower Perspective in MapsFragment on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, augmented-reality, gyroscope

I'm wondering if it's possible to switch to a "navigation view" with the Google Maps API.
By navigation view, I mean the "3D Follower Perspective" one experiences when using Google Maps API to navigate to a certain location. 
I do **not** want to use any navigation functionality, I just want something like this follower perspective.

I've seen this view on a Windows Phone App and it additionally used about every sensor the device offered, such as compass and gyroscope to achieve almost some kind of an augmented reality feeling as the map turned the same way as oneself did.
Is anything comparable available on Android?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible.

Google I/O 2013 had nice demo that shows something similar to what you want to achieve.

Start watching at 21:30: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oZiK_NJuG8

They actually show some code there that you will use.

Comment: Thanks for that hint, I'm going to try that. I will post some snippets when I'm happy with the result.